# What's the next symbol in this sequence

Tags: pattern, symbols

I came up with this puzzle the other day. It may not too original or particularly challenging, but I thought it could be fun. 
What's the next symbol in this sequence? <sub><sup>(There's also a hint in here somewhere)</sup></sub>

> $ { \large \prime \prime } \qquad 
>     {\prime \,}_{\Large\prime}^{\Large\prime} \qquad 
>     { \Large \circ } \qquad 
>     {_{\Large\prime}^{\Large\prime}\Large \circ } \qquad 
>     {\Large\prime\,_{\Large\circ}^{\Large\circ} } \qquad 
>     {\large ? } $

Comment: Inspired from Roman numbers? :)

Comment: @L16H7 Sort of. I thought if a tablet containing an ancient numeral system were discovered with no context, we would need to also find some sort of numerical pattern or formula that could be worked out to understand what the symbols represented. The symbols and patterns were chosen mostly for aesthetic purposes, the similarity to Roman numerals was coincidental.

Comment: FYI, the question mark is not a part of the sequence.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is

> $\prime\,_{\Large\prime}^{\Large\prime}\,_{\Large\circ}^{\Large\circ}$

because the symbols represent

> the prime numbers, where $\prime$ has a value of 1 and $\circ$ has a value of 5.

The hint is that

> $\prime$ is the "prime" symbol.

Comment: Yup. Answered in under 20 minutes. Hopefully my next puzzle will pose a bit more of a challenge :)